# Ubuntu 20.04 started acting strange, shortcuts not working suddenly and cant click on windows (can only drag them)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I cannot explain properly what is happening as I have no idea what is happening. Basically from what I've experienced up to now is the following.

- Super (windows key) doesn't open all of the open aplications anymore.
- Alt + Tab started showing me all the tabs before switching, while it
  used to just switch between last 2 tabs.
- This happens and stops, but when trying to close a tab or open a new tab in chrome I cannot click it. When I try to click it turns into the grab cursos. This happens and stops and I have no idea what causes it.
- Ctrl+ Alt + T not starting the terminal as well (now it's working)

Tried restarting and shutting down. I literally just sat on my PC and this has started happening, super awkward. The super key still doesn't work. I am using gnome and Ubuntu 20.04

EDIT: Additional info

[lshw -class display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9lA8.png)

[gsettings extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXxKi.png)

The problem was that ALT+F2 wasn't doing anything (gnome shell wasn't appearing). Super key does absolutely nothing. I've also had another bug where clicking on the browser on the left was opening new browsers instead of going into the already open browser.

I haven't done anything between the last boot and this one, but everything is broken at the moment when it comes to shortcuts and user interface/ GUI. I've tried to update and upgrade but no changes.

I have no idea what is happening or what the other valid info could be. I can only say what is currently behaving unexpectedly. Everything else seems to work fine, I can use programs and such, but I sometimes cannot type in the browsers either.

When it starts bugging I cannot even press the record button it immediately start dragging.

[Lag recorded on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGQ9.jpg)

EDIT2: After clean boot (next day) seems to be working as expected. But what was it? It was super annoying.

Comment: Include info on your graphics card `lshw -class display`. Describe better what happens if you press Super. If possible, include a screenshot. Provide information on extensions you have installed: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`. Indicate whether you have a clue as to when this started happening. Did you change something? Include all extra info in your post: use "edit".

Comment: also try reloading GNOME `Alt+F2` then r then `Enter`

Comment: Added more info in the edits